# Javascript, compare element from array, if true execute a function

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get this thing going - it is basically a really simple game where you have to guess which runner will cross the line first.

[image: visual]
Basically, its a track with 4 runners.
The `search` button gives a random number from the array. And this number shows which runner takes a step forward to the finish line.

I had this thing built in 2 parts. First, where I made the Random number generator and the other part was just the track. I was able to make the runners move separately with 4 buttons. Now i have no idea how to make this work.

I tried different code but still nothing worked. I am new to JavaScript with a little bit of PHP knowledge  and I think the way PHP works is just not the way i can make this work.

I tried different ways to compare the outcome of the random number generator and I think this is the closest I got and that I am missing a tiny bit of code that I just can't figure out.

Thanks.

```js
var runner = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
];

function GetValue() {
  var random = runner[Math.floor(Math.random() * runner.length)];
  //alert(random);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
  for (var i = runner.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (runner[i] === random) {
      runner.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = runner;
}

var imgObjgroen = null;
var imgObjrood = null;
var imgObjgeel = null;
var imgObjblauw = null;

function init() {
  imgObjblauw = document.getElementsByClassName('loperblauw');
  imgObjblauw.style.left = '35px';
  imgObjgeel = document.getElementsByClassName('lopergeel');
  imgObjgeel.style.left = '35px';
  imgObjrood = document.getElementsByClassName('loperrood');
  imgObjrood.style.left = '35px';
  imgObjgroen = document.getElementsByClassName('lopergroen');
  imgObjgroen.style.left = '35px';
}

if (random === 1) {
  imgObjgroen.style.left = parseInt(imgObjgroen.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
}

if (random === 2) {
  imgObjrood.style.left = parseInt(imgObjrood.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
}

if (random === 3) {
  imgObjgeel.style.left = parseInt(imgObjgeel.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
}

if (random === 4) {
  imgObjblauw.style.left = parseInt(imgObjblauw.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img id="baan" src="baan.png">
  <img id="lopergroen" src="lopergroen.png">
  <img id="loperrood" src="loperrood.png">
  <img id="lopergeel" src="lopergeel.png">
  <img id="loperblauw" src="loperblauw.png">
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />

<p id="message" class="test">test</p>



<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: why not use a single counter for every runner. after random choice, you could just increment the position and check if the actual runner finished.

Comment: the 'game' doesn't work that way, it has to be one array, See i didnt mention it but it is actually a deck of cards. Where 1 are diamonds and 2 are spades and so on. And i want to see it visual that every generated number, is one step so that it actually looks like a race. Sorry for bad english, perhaps also the reason i didn't fully understand ur answer.

Comment: Running your code snippet = `Uncaught ReferenceError: random is not defined`. I'd start off by getting your snippet working, and demonstrating the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not really performant, because you need to loop and test all array elements, I think what you are looking for is [**Javascript array.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). It will perfectly achieve the test you are trying to do and filter the result.

Your code would be :

```
var random = runner[Math.floor(Math.random() * runner.length)];

document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(function(value){
          return value === random;
);
```

Comment: thanks, I know what i did wrong. Just like you said i have to loop all elements.

Answer (score 1):

The four `if` statements (`if (random === 1)` etc.) together make up for your (currently not existing) `move` function. Wrap them in a function and call it by the end of `GetValue`:

```js
function movePlayer(playerIndex) {
  if (playerIndex === 1) {
    imgObjgroen.style.left = parseInt(imgObjgroen.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (playerIndex === 2) {
    imgObjrood.style.left = parseInt(imgObjrood.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (playerIndex === 3) {
    imgObjgeel.style.left = parseInt(imgObjgeel.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (playerIndex === 4) {
    imgObjblauw.style.left = parseInt(imgObjblauw.style.left) + 95 + 'px';
  }
}

function getValue() {
  /* your code */
  movePlayer(random);
}
```

This should get you further, but is still far from the "easiest" way of implementing this.

I'd advice you to break up your code in small functions with clear names. Use arrays for lists of items (e.g.: store your players in an array). Keep in mind that code in functions only runs when the function is called (e.g.: `GetValue()` runs the block in `function GetValue() { }`).

If you feel you need some more help moving stuff around, let me know.

**Edit:** The "next step" in getting your code to work I proposed, in a snippet. Note: I had to make some more changes for it to work:

- You can not use the `random` variable outside the `GetValue` function.
- I had to select by id instead of class to target your elements
- I changed `style.left` to `style.marginLeft` so I needed a bit less css

*Disclaimer: This by no means fixes all of your game. I don't think it'll help if we rewrite all of it. Once you understand this next step, you should be able to slowly solve the other problems as well :)*

```js
var runner = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
];

function GetValue() {
  var random = runner[Math.floor(Math.random() * runner.length)];
  //alert(random);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = random;
  for (var i = runner.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (runner[i] === random) {
      runner.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = runner;
  move(random);
}

var imgObjgroen = null;
var imgObjrood = null;
var imgObjgeel = null;
var imgObjblauw = null;

function init() {
  imgObjblauw = document.getElementById('loperblauw');
  imgObjblauw.style.marginLeft = '35px';
  imgObjgeel = document.getElementById('lopergeel');
  imgObjgeel.style.marginLeft = '35px';
  imgObjrood = document.getElementById('loperrood');
  imgObjrood.style.marginLeft = '35px';
  imgObjgroen = document.getElementById('lopergroen');
  imgObjgroen.style.marginLeft = '35px';
}

function move(random) {
  if (random === 1) {
    imgObjgroen.style.marginLeft = parseInt(imgObjgroen.style.marginLeft) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (random === 2) {
    imgObjrood.style.marginLeft = parseInt(imgObjrood.style.marginLeft) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (random === 3) {
    imgObjgeel.style.marginLeft = parseInt(imgObjgeel.style.marginLeft) + 95 + 'px';
  }

  if (random === 4) {
    imgObjblauw.style.marginLeft = parseInt(imgObjblauw.style.marginLeft) + 95 + 'px';
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img id="baan" src="baan.png">
  <img id="lopergroen" src="lopergroen.png">
  <img id="loperrood" src="loperrood.png">
  <img id="lopergeel" src="lopergeel.png">
  <img id="loperblauw" src="loperblauw.png">
</div>

<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();" />

<p id="message" class="test">test</p>
<p id="demo1"></p>
```

Comment: thanks for responding, i try this out and let you know how it works for me

Comment: i am asuming that the last line of code movePlayer(runner); has to be movePlayer(random); but still i can't manage to fix it, seems like once i use a variable i cant use it again. idk

Comment: I included a snippet that shows how this small change should get you futher.

Comment: thanks i got it working, not on this way because i thought i had to change a lot. But thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing I see that you're missing:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
```

Should be

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1
```

Because as is, you're only getting 0-3, not 1-4. So you can change that or your if-else conditions. You can test this in the console.

Comment: jea but i did -1 with the variables in the loop so this makes no difference, and i tried changing the if statements a bit but it didnt work for me. still trying tho

Comment: ow and btw it is not 4, its 52 its the number of values in side the array. still appreciate for thinking with me